# algorithm to find blocks of trends

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-mining, windows-clustering

Let's say I have a a 24 lines of data, such that each line represents an hour in the day. What I want to achieve is to implement an algorithm that can detect trends in the data and can divide it into 2 blocks - a "good" block and a "bad" block. for example, in the attached image you can see that at line 6 a good block begins and ends in line 19. line 0 also has a good score but it is not part of a block so the algorithm should know how to handle this situation.
I think it's about clustering but couldn't find something simple enough that fits our needs.
Looking forward for any advice.

[image]

Comment: The definition of a "good" block seems subjective. It would be good if you could specify it somehow. Would you say something like: "sustained values over X in most of 90% of the samples (not counting start/end)?

Comment: Isn't that simple thresholding and analyzing connected components?

Comment: @NicoSchertler: Yes, but a "while (value >= threshold)" linear scan would be enough to find these "components", and you can simply check the length of each on the fly and report it if necessary.

Comment: Actually I missed the scenario where we have one bad value in a good block. In this case it still should be a good block.and this is a good place to say that good block is just a block where almost values are above threshold (maximum 2 that aren't)

Answer (score 1):

```
start = -1
Append a below-threshold value to the end of the data array x[]
For i from 1 to n:
    If x[i] >= thresholdValue:
        if start == -1:
            start = i
    Else:
        If start != -1 and i - start >= thresholdLength:
            ReportGoodBlock(start, i-1)
        start = -1
```